# The Arduino IDE can’t find my Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, led, arduino-uno-smd

My Arduino has all of its LEDs on. The `Rx`, `Tx` and `L` LEDs are all on and my computer can’t see it (it's an SMD edition).

Answer (score 1):

It can have many reasons, but you can try the following:

**First time use?**

- Check if you need to install a special driver for CH340

**Environment/Software problems**

- Try another USB port
- Change USB cable
- Restart Arduino IDE
- Restart computer
- Reinstall Arduino IDE

**Hardware problems**

- Test using another Arduino
- Test using another computer/laptop
- Replace USB cable
- The Arduino is (partly) broken, nothing much to do here

Answer (score 0):

The USB interface chip controls the Rx & Tx lights.  I suspect you fried it.
Does the '328P feel warm or hot to the touch? That's usually a sign that it has been damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an "official" Arduino purchased from their website? If it isn't, chances are you need to install CH340 drivers for your computer before the Arduino will be recognized. Drivers can be found [here](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html) Have you successfully used this device with your computer before?